# Formalizing a proof for $ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} a_k = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

Let $(a_n)_n$ be a sequence of non-negative real numbers.

I fail to see a formal proof of the following (conjectured) equality:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} a_k = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)a_n. 
$$

Roughly speaking the claim follows from expanding the LHS: 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} a_k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_k + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} a_k + \ldots + \sum_{k=i}^{\infty} a_k + \ldots 
$$
Now it is easy to see that each term $a_k$ appears in exactly $(k+1)$ terms in RHS (e.g. writing column-wise the different sums), so it is intuitively clear that it has to be $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)a_n$.

However I am not satisfied of this informal hand-waving proof. Any hints/helps to make it formal? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe consider $[0;+\infty)^2$ integer grid of indexes and try to sum in vertical-to-horizontal and horizontal-to-vertical order? With $a_{n,k}=a_k$

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Yeah that seems also to be a way but honestly seems a bit overkill, doesn't it? We would have to justify the interchange of two series (which is fine, $a_n \ge 0$) but I felt like it was easier... Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use the indicator function

$$\mathbf{1}_{\{k\geqslant n\}} = \begin{cases}1,&k \geqslant n \\0, &k < n\end{cases},$$

and nonnegativity of $a_k$ to obtain

$$\sum_{n = 0}^\infty\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty   \mathbf{1}_{\{k\geqslant n\}}a_k \,\underbrace{= \sum_{k = 0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty   \mathbf{1}_{\{k\geqslant n\}}a_k }_{\text{applying Tonelli's theorem}} = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty a_k\sum_{n=0}^\infty   \mathbf{1}_{\{k\geqslant n\}} \\ = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty a_k\sum_{n=0}^k   (1) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)a_k = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)a_n$$
Clearly, the last step is just replacing letter "k" with letter "n".

Comment: Why does the non-negativity of the sequence make a difference here?

Comment: @AmeetSharma:  Switching sums holds when the terms are nonnegative by Tonelli’s theorem. That theorem specifically applies to nonnegative series.  Fubini’s theorem is more general and applies if the terms change sign but an additional hypothesis is required (absolute sumability). Here OP has told us the terms are nonnegative.

Comment: Is there a good reference for the use of the terms "Tonelli's theorem"  and "Fubini's theorem" in the specific context of the summation of double series? Apostol, for one, doesn't use either term in this way. The same goes for the other textbooks listed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2969163/). I had never come across either term in such a context until seeing "Tonelli's theorem" mentioned a few times in MSE. I've searched the Internet twice  recently without finding anything that doesn't appear to make the result depend on general measure theory (and that would *really* be overkill).

Answer (score 2):

By double counting, since the sum by columns must be equal to the sum by rows, we obtain that

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} a_k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{k} a_k= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k\sum_{n=0}^{k}1 =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)a_k$$

[image]

Refer also to the related

- [How to change the order of summation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1876828/505767)

Comment: Yes, this is wonderful and the picture is exactly what I have also drawn (only on the paper ;-)). Only small question: how you justify rigorously the first equality? How do you swap the sums? Intuitively OK; formally? Is it a theorem? Thanks.

Comment: @Romeo I think it is more than sufficient as a proof. In the first case we sum by columns in the other by rows and the two sums must be equals. In case you are iterested in other ways, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3443147/505767) you can find something.

Comment: We can interchange the order of summation by Tonelli's theorem, since the $a_n$ are nonnegative.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's actually less trouble to prove Tonelli's theorem
(which I imagine in this context means something like
Theorem 8.43 of Apostol, *Mathematical Analysis* (2nd ed. 1974),
although the more general* proposition (5.3.6) of
Dieudonné, *Foundations of Modern Analysis* (1969) could also be used)
than it is to prove this result without using Tonelli's theorem!
However, nothing daunted $\ldots$

<sup>*Minor correction (not needed for this argument): it isn't strictly
accurate to describe Dieudonne's (5.3.6) as more general than
Apostol's Theorem 8.43. I listed some other references in a comment
on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2969163) related question.</sup>

Define the triangular numbers:
$$
t_k = \frac{k(k+1)}{2} \quad (k \geqslant 0),
$$
and the infinite sequence $(b_r)_{r\geqslant0}$, where:
$$
b_r = a_k \quad (k \geqslant 0,\ t_k \leqslant r < t_{k+1}),
$$
thus:
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccccccccc}
r & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & \cdots \\
b_r & a_0 & a_1 & a_1 & a_2 & a_2 & a_2 & a_3 & a_3 & a_3 & a_3 & \cdots
\end{array}
$$
For $N \geqslant 0$, define the $(t_{N+1})^\text{th}$
partial sum of the series $\sum_{r=0}^\infty b_r$, thus:
$$
s_N = \sum_{r=0}^{t_{N+1}-1}b_r = \sum_{k=0}^N(k+1)a_k
\quad (N \geqslant 0).
$$
Consider this infinite triangular array:
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \\
\text{row } 3 & & & & b_9 & \cdots \\
\text{row } 2 & & & b_5 & b_8 & \cdots \\
\text{row } 1 & & b_2 & b_4 & b_7 & \cdots \\
\text{row } 0 & b_0 & b_1 & b_3 & b_6 & \cdots \\
\hline
\text{sums} & a_0 & 2a_1 & 3a_2 & 4a_3 & \cdots
\end{array}
$$
The $n^\text{th}$ row of the array is the infinite sequence
$\big(c_k^{(n)}\big)_{k\geqslant{n}}$, where:
$$
c_k^{(n)} = b_{t_k + n} = a_k \quad (k \geqslant n \geqslant 0).
$$
In terms of the $c_k^{(n)}$, the selected partial sums of the series
$(b_r)_{r\geqslant0}$ are given by:
$$
s_N = \sum_{n=0}^N\sum_{k=n}^Nc_k^{(n)} \quad (N \geqslant 0).
$$
For $N \geqslant n \geqslant 0$, the $(N-n)^\text{th}$ remainder of
the infinite series $\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}c_k^{(n)}$ is the sum of a
subsequence of $(b_r)$ whose indices satisfy $r\geqslant{t_{N+1}}$.
For $n > N \geqslant 0$, the entire infinite series
$\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}c_k^{(n)}$ is the sum of such a subsequence of
$(b_r)$. Also,
$$
t_k + n \ne t_{k'} + n'
\quad (k \geqslant n \geqslant 0, \ k' \geqslant n' \geqslant 0,
\ n \ne n').
$$
This means that all the series just mentioned are the sums of
pairwise *disjoint* subsequences of the sequence $(b_r)$ with
indices $r\geqslant{t_{N+1}}$.

Now we begin to consider questions of convergence.  It is required
to prove:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} a_k =
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n+1)a_n,
$$
where $a_n \geqslant 0$ for all $n$.  This is trivial if $a_n = 0$
for all $n$, so we assume from now on that $a_n > 0$ for some $n$,
whence the sums on either side of the identity, if well-defined, are
also strictly positive.  If the iterated infinite sum on the left
hand side is well-defined and equal to $S > 0$, then $S$ is an
upper bound for all the finite sums:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^N\sum_{k=n}^N a_k = \sum_{n=0}^N(n+1)a_n
\quad (N \geqslant 0),
$$
whence the infinite sum on the right hand side of the conjectured
identity is also well-defined.

It is therefore enough to prove that if the sum on the right hand
side of the identity is well-defined and equal to $S > 0$, then the
iterated sum on the left hand side of the identity is also
well-defined and equal to $S$.

Given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $N$ so that:
$$
\sum_{r=t_{N+1}}^\infty b_r = \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty(n+1)a_n
\leqslant \epsilon.
$$

> **Lemma**
>   Let $m$ be an integer, and let
>   $(b_r)_{k \geqslant m}$ be a sequence of non-negative numbers such
>   that $\sum_{r=m}^\infty b_r$ converges.  For any infinite set
>   $$
> L = \{l(0), l(1), l(2), \ldots\} \text{ where }
> m \leqslant l(0) < l(1) < l(2) < \cdots,
> $$
>   define
>   $$
> \sigma(L) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty b_{l(i)}.
> $$
>   Then for any infinite sequence of pairwise disjoint infinite subsets
>   $L_0, L_1, L_2 \ldots$ of $\{r \in \mathbb{Z} : r \geqslant m\}$ we
>   have
>   $$
> \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sigma(L_n) \leqslant \sum_{r=m}^\infty b_r.
> $$
>   **Proof**
>   In the contrary case, there are $\eta > 0$ and an integer $M \geqslant 1$ such that
>   $$
> \sum_{n=0}^{M-1} \sigma(L_n) = \sum_{r=m}^\infty b_r + 2\eta.
> $$
>   From $L_n$ ($n = 0, 1, \ldots, M-1$) take enough terms of the series
>   for $\sigma(L_n)$ to give a partial sum greater than
>   $\sigma(L_n) - \eta/M$. By the disjointness condition, all these
>   terms together have a sum greater than
>   $$
> \sum_{n=0}^{M-1} \sigma(L_n) - \eta > \sum_{r=m}^\infty b_r,
> $$
>   which is a contradiction.

The lemma shows that the $(N-n)^\text{th}$ remainder of
the infinite series $\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}c_k^{(n)}$ for
$n = 0, 1, \ldots, N$, together with the entirety of the series
$\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}c_k^{(n)}$ for $n = N+1, N+2, \ldots$, 
form an infinite series whose sum is at most $\epsilon$.
Denote this by $\sum_{n=0}^\infty d_n$. Then:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^N\sum_{k=n}^\infty c_k^{(n)} =
\sum_{n=0}^N\left(\sum_{k=n}^N c_k^{(n)} + d_n\right) =
\sum_{n=0}^N\sum_{k=n}^N c_k^{(n)} + \sum_{n=0}^N d_n,
$$
therefore:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k =
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=n}^\infty c_k^{(n)} =
\sum_{n=0}^N\sum_{k=n}^N c_k^{(n)} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty d_n
= s_N+ \sum_{n=0}^\infty d_n.
$$
This shows that the iterated sum on the left hand side of the
conjectured identity is well-defined, and its value lies between
$s_N$ and $s_N + \epsilon$. The two sides of the identity therefore
differ by most $\epsilon$. Since $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, this
proves that they are equal.